# adding a subview in custom table cell on scroll of table the subview disappear what to do that subview returns back on cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I am adding a **subview** on long press in a **custom** table cell but when I scroll the table, the **subview disappears**.

What should I do so that when I scroll back, that subview still **shows/appears** on that cell or in other words i say **cell remains selected**?

```
- (IBAction)click4:(id)sender
{
    //
    self.lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    [self.lpgr setMinimumPressDuration:1];
    [self.contentView addGestureRecognizer:self.lpgr];
}
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if ([sender isEqual:self.lpgr]) {
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        {
            self.actionButtonView = [[PerformAction alloc]initWithNibName:@"PerformAction" bundle:Nil];
            [self.thirdImageView addSubview:self.actionButtonView.view];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything works as expected. I think you `cellForRowAtIndexPath` works like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[self cellIdentifierForIndexPath:indexPath] forIndexPath:indexPath];
    id item = [self itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // some configuration here.
    return cell;
}
```

So when you reach `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` you have cell as designed in nib (or on storyboard).

If you want to achieve what you're trying to do, you can add view and make it hidden based on cell status. Update this status with long tap.

Answer (score 0):

Init custom `UITableViewCell` with separate identifier. This will load all the cells in `UITableView` and remains as it is when you scroll `UITableView`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellIdentifier%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier];
}
return cell;
}
```

But this will also consume more memory because all cells are loaded in `UITableView`.